# Substract two QString

Tags: qstring

I´m trying to substract two hours.

```
QString 1 = "11:00";
QString 2 = "10:00";
```

I would like to save the result from (11:00 - 10:00) into another QString.

Does anyone know how could I do this?

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [QTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html):

Convert your QStrings to QTime:

```
QTime a = QTime::fromString("11:00", "HH:mm");  
QTime b = QTime::fromString("12:00", "HH:mm");
```

Get difference in msecs:

```
int differenceInMsecs = a.msecsTo(b);
```

(Read [QTime:msecsTo() documentation!](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#msecsTo))

Convert msecs ins whatever you want and put it in QString